# Help in test class - Comparable interface and Page Reference

Tags: apex, unit-test

Pagereference method :

```
public pagereference setPageParameters(){

    PageReference pageRef = Page.DTRC_Products;        

    string accountid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    pageRef.getParameters().put('id', accountid);

    if(!String.isEmpty(SortBy) && SortBy.equals('asc')){
         pageRef.getParameters().put('SortBy', 'Desc');
    } else {
         pageRef.getParameters().put('SortBy', 'asc');
    }       
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;

}
```

Comparable method :

```
public ProdWrapper(){
    public ProdWrapper(Integer AccountNo , String SortBy){
        this.AccountNo = AccountNo;
        this.SortBy = sortBy;

    }
    public Integer compareTo(Object ObjToCompare) {

        ProdWrapper compareExpNum = (ProductWrapper)ObjToCompare;

        if (sortBy == 'desc'){
            if (eAccountNo == compareExpNum.AccountNo) return 0;
            if (AccountNo < compareExpNum.AccountNo) return 1;
            return -1;
        }
        else if(sortBy == 'asc') {
            if (AccountNo == compareExpNum.AccountNo) return 0;
            if (AccountNo > compareExpNum.AccountNo) return 1;
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Need some idea on how to cover the test class.

Comment: Have you started to create a test class? If so, editing your question to include it would be helpful. If you're new to unit testing and have no idea where to start, the [Apex Testing module on Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing) would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give you specifics when you have not even started/posted a test method nor the class name that implements the comparable interface

When you implement the test method and call `.sort()` on the class that implements the comparable interface the method will be covered (lines) but not tested (asserts).

You will need to assert the sorting is as expected using system asserts

Also, in your case you have some custom sort logic so you will need to set those properties `sortBy` for example and validate it is working as expected

Most likely you will end up with the following test methods

```
private static testmethod void sortDesc_eAccountNoFirst(){.....}

private static testmethod void sortDesc_eAccountNoLast(){.....}

private static testmethod void sortAsc_AccountNoFirst(){.....}

private static testmethod void sortAsc_AccountNoLast(){.....}
```

If you are new to testing visit [TrailHead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing)